# how to split this existing database table to reduce redundancy

Tags: sql, database, relational

I have an existing table which is too big to process. I tried to split it into two tables, and still not satisfied.

Here is the table look like, (package_id is a foreign key to the package table),

```
    child_company title_category title_level revision start_date package_id
 ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    c1             manager         senior      0       2015/1/1    120
    c1             manager         senior      1       2014/7/1    119
    c1             architect       senior      0       2014/7/1    70

    c2             architect       junior      0       2015/3/1    70

    c3             manager         senior      0       2015/1/1    120
    c3             manager         senior      1       2014/7/1    119

    c4             manager         senior      0       2015/2/1    122
    c4             manager         senior      1       2014/2/1    102
    c4             manager         senior      2       2013/7/1    101

    c5             manager         senior      0       2015/1/1    120
    c5             manager         senior      1       2014/7/1    119
```

The problem with this table is that, many child companies have similar salary information and their history. (History is indicated by `revision`. `revision = 0` indicate the current salary info.). For example, `c1`, `c3`, and `c5` both have the same pay for senior managers.

What is the best way to split this table to reduce redundancy?

I tried to split it like this

```
    child_company title_category title_level group_id
 --------------------------------------------------------
    c1             manager         senior      0 
    c1             architect       senior      1
    c2             architect       junior      2
    c3             manager         senior      0
    c4             manager         senior      3
    c5             manager         senior      0
```

And

```
id     group_id start_date package_id
1      0        2015/1/1    120
2      0        2014/7/1    119
3      1        2014/7/1    70
4      2        2015/3/1    70
5      3        2015/2/1    122
6      3        2014/2/1    102
7      3        2013/7/1    101
```

Better solutions? Thanks

Comment: How big is this table?  What are the bottlenecks you are having?  It is hard to imagine that such a table is so large that breaking it up into different tables is the right solution.  Typically, relational databases offer other methods for handling larger tables.

Comment: What are the relationships of each column? It looks like you could move Title (title_category and title_level) out into its own table, but I don't know enough about the structure to help.

Comment: Well, this is just an example, the real table have about half a billion records and more columns.

Comment: Title Category is actually a foreign key to a table about thousands of records. title_level has only 4 values. `revision number` shows the revision to `start date` and `package id` to any group of `child company name`, `title category` and `title level`.  `start date` is the date when the new `package` got into effect.

Comment: @JohnSmith . . . I assume you have partitioned and indexed the table appropriately to address the performance concerns.  It would appear that you have a data modeling problem, where the data in this table should be split into different tables -- but not really by row.

Comment: @GordonLinoff . I agree that the existing table has a modeling problem. But I just don't know how to correct it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a model I developed about eight years ago using what I call Version Normal Form (vnf). The first table is the main entity table that contains static, unchanging data, or data that may change but you aren't tracking the changes. The second table contains each version, a new version being entered whenever the underlying data changes.

```
create table Static(
    ID    int not null primary key auto increment,
    Company  varchar( 8 ) not null,
    Title varchar( 32 ) not null,
    Level varchar( 16 ) not null,
    Created date not null default SysDate
);
create table Versions(
    ID    int not null references Static( ID ),
    Effective date default SysDate,
    PackageID int references Package( ID ),
    constraint PK_Versions primary key( ID, Effective )
};
```

To represent the data you show (using the oldest start_date to simulate a reasonable creation date):

```
Static
ID   Company Title     Level   Created
 1   C1      Manager   Senior  2014/7/1
 2   C1      Architect Senior  2014/7/1
 3   C2      Architect Junior  2015/3/1
 4   C3      Manager   Senior  2014/7/1
 5   C4      Manager   Senior  2013/7/1
 6   C5      Manager   Senior  2014/7/1

Versions
ID   Effective PackageID
 1   2015/1/1        120
 1   2014/7/1        119
 2   2014/7/1         70
 3   2015/3/1         70
 4   2015/1/1        120
 4   2014/7/1        119
 5   2015/2/1        122
 5   2014/2/1        102
 5   2013/7/1        101
 6   2015/1/1        120
 6   2014/7/1        119
```

The key to making this easy to use for the app developers is views. First, the view to show only the current data. The current version is the version with the most recent Effective date:

```
create view Current as
    select  s.Company as child_company, s.Title as title_category,
            s.Level as title_level, v.Effective as start_date
            v.PackageID as package_id
    from    Static   s
    join    Versions v
        on  v.ID   = s.ID
        and v.Effective =(
            select  Max( Effective )
            from    Versions
            where   ID = v.ID );
```

The other view is a history view. It shows all the versions, past and current:

```
create view History as
    select  s.Company as child_company, s.Title as title_category,
            s.Level as title_level, v.Effective as start_date
            v.PackageID as package_id
    from    Static   s
    join    Versions v
        on  v.ID   = s.ID;
```

Notice it's the same query, just without the last four lines.

The History view has an `instead of` trigger that does nothing, thus rendering it read-only. The Current view has `instead of` triggers that manages the underlying structure. In particular, the `update` trigger performs an insert of a new version instead of an actual update.

This looks somewhat complicated, but among the benefits are

- it uses normalization, which developers already know about.
- the versions are independent of each other -- that is, when a new version is inserted, none of the other versions must be modified in any way.
- if a change is scheduled to take place in the future, you can go ahead and enter the change with the Effective set to that future date. The current version remains current until that time arrives at which point the scheduled version becomes the new current version.
- it takes a minor modification to obtain complete bi-temporal access to the data. It doesn't look like that's what you need but you never know.

Note: to use the "future version" capability, just add `and Effective <= Sysdate` to the subquery of the Current view.